# Counting rows in 2 CSV files for comparison

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a PowerShell script that almost does what I want.

Basically there are CSV file feeds that are written to a specific location and stored by year and month. I have to compare the number of rows between the two newest CSV files, as a large discrepancy indicates an issue.

Currently my script fetches the newest CSV file and returns the row count with no problems, but I can't work out how to get it to return the row count for the 2 newest files. It is likely due to the way I've structured the script:

```cs
$datemonth = (Get-Date).Month 
$dateyear  = (Get-Date).Year 

## get latest csv files
$dir = "\\160.1.1.98\c$\Scheduled Task Software\ScheduledTask\Application Files\ScheduledTask_1_0_0_9\Files\$dateyear\$datemonth\SentFeedFiles"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir |
          Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -First 1

## get path to csv files, add headers and count number of rows.
$filepath = $dir + '\' + $latest

$CSVCOUNT = (Import-Csv $filepath -Header 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28).Count
```

If I change to `-First 2` then I get the following error:

> Import-Csv : Could not find file '\16.1.1.18\c$\Scheduled Task Software\ScheduledTask\Application Files\ScheduledTask_1_0_0_9\Files\2017\3\SentFeedFiles\lkrlkr200317.csv lkrlkr19017.csv'.

I know why I'm getting this error - its trying to join the two file names into one path. However, I'm at a loss of how to get around this. I'm thinking a loop may be required but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Which two files? Just the first two in the directory, ordered by LastAccessTime?

Comment: Yes exactly. The two newest ones in the directory. The directory will change depending on the month and year.

Comment: You have two results... so pipe them to a foreach statement... while in there, do the CSVcount on whatever you call those objects or $_ if you don't name them.  Look into powershell foreach statments

Comment: Do you need to actually treat these files as CSVs (i.e., are you going to be processing the data in the file afterward, within this script)? If not, then `(Get-Content $file).Length` will get you the number of lines in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chucked 3 CSV files in f:\tmp locally to test:

```
$dir = "F:\tmp"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 2

($files | Get-Content).Count
```

Import-Csv only deals with a single file as far as I remember - so you can't pass two file paths to it.

If you want to use Import-CSV (for ignoring headers etc), you can foreach file, but you have to pass the full path into it:

```
($files.FullName | % { Import-Csv -Path $_ }).Count
```

To get two separate results, do the following:

Include headers:

```
($files[0] | Get-Content).count
($files[1] | Get-Content).count
```

Exclude headers:

```
(Import-Csv -Path $files[0].FullName).Count
(Import-Csv -Path $files[1].FullName).Count
```

Comment: That seems better - but it appears to add the two together? I'm guessing I will need a foreach loop, but not sure how I refer to the objects

Comment: Just sorting it now

Comment: Not sure what you mean by adding the two together? Is that not what you're trying to do? My original example (top one) included the CSV headers.

Comment: I'm looking for two separate results. When I ran your solution it added the row counts of the two files together.

I want to be able to compare the two numbers.

Comment: `$Result1=($files[0].FullName | % { Import-Csv -Path $_ }).Count; $Result2 = ($files[1].FullName | % { Import-Csv -Path $_ }).Count`

Comment: Simpler: `$files | % { @(Import-Csv $_.FullName -Header (1..28)).Count }`. Or `$files | % { @(Get-Content $_.FullName).Count }` if the files don't have headers in the first place.

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify that :) $files is an array, so as John says you can use the indexer to access it - or just run two queries against the Get-ChildItem

Comment: @Ricky - what are you doing with the results afterwards? Do you need two separate variables, or just an object with references to the counts? Your answer may affect the code - there's some nice shorthand in Powershell.

Comment: I'm not doing anything with them really - just basically wanting two figures for row counts.
I'm currently checking the row counts manually by opening the file, so this is just to automate that process.